# Is there an equivalent of R finalfit package in python?

Tags: python, r, statistics, package, logistic-regression

In R there is a quite convenient package for statistical analysis : [finalfit](https://finalfit.org/)

It enables to present in a succint form tables of results with Odd Ratios extracted from Logistic Regression in univariate and multivariate. Below is an exemple of the kind of tables I would like to obtain :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbkcd.png)

I would like to obtain the same kind of outputs in python, is there a library that can do the same thing ?

To my understanding there is no direct possibility with python library `statsmodel` to obtain this kind of output...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.